# openpyxl library StopIteration error when opening xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, vba, openpyxl

I am trying to open a excel file that is 1.5mb, it has 25 sheets and no more than 1000 rows per sheet. there is nothign special about the file. it is not read-only as well.
I need to perform some automation tasks to the file but when i try to import it onto my Jupyther environment i get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-4584f4eff7cc> in <module>()
----> 1 eppm = oxl.load_workbook('DCB EPPM Demand Extract 2.xlsx')

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py in load_workbook(filename, read_only, 
keep_vba, data_only, guess_types, keep_links)
222 
223     apply_stylesheet(archive, wb) # bind styles to workbook
--> 224     pivot_caches = parser.pivot_caches
225 
226     # get worksheets

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/openpyxl/packaging/workbook.py in pivot_caches(self)
123         d = {}
124         for c in self.caches:
--> 125             cache = get_rel(self.archive, self.rels, id=c.id, 
cls=CacheDefinition)
126             records = get_rel(self.archive, cache.deps, cache.id, 
RecordList)
127             cache.records = records

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/openpyxl/packaging/relationship.py in get_rel(archive, deps, id, 
cls)
151         rel = deps[id]
152     else:
--> 153         rel = next(deps.find(cls.rel_type))
154 
155     path = rel.target

StopIteration:
```

I cannot share the file because it contains company information and I cannot create dummy data to recreate the file because the Python error does not seem to indicate where the error is occuring.
I have looked for a similar error on SO but the StopIteration error normally happens when people are working with loops.
any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: [Edit] your question and show the `openpyxl` version and tell if you have verified Excel can read the `.xlsx` file.

Comment: @stovfl the openpyxl version is 2.5.3 and i can open other .xlsx files. i only have a problem with this particular file and my best guess is because it has so many tabs but i need somebody to confirm that or point me in the right direction please?

Comment: My request was **not**, ***"can open other .xlsx files"***, i asked: **Can you open this `.xlsx` in question with Excel**? Your `openpyxl` version is outdated, update to the current [Version:2.6.2](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: @stovfl yes, i can open the .xlsx file with excel. and i have moved all the tabs to a different workbook and the file opens in openpyxl, the issue is that i need the original file to open. version has been updated with the same result.

Comment: If you think it's a bug in `openpyxl`, file a issue to [openpyxl/issues](http://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not with openpyxl or the python environment. the issue was with the way the original workbook had been saved. although it was saved as a .xlsx document but it was not an excel workbook, it was a Strict Open XML Spreadsheet .xlsx
so at first glance it was assumed that this file will open with no issues.
once the file was changed to an excel Workbook .xlsx then the file loaded with no issues.

I hope this post helps people that have committed the same mistake i have!